# nested arrays how to foreach it proper using smarty (loop in loop)

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I can not figure out how to loop my array in smarty, i have read the docs but some some reason i just can get it right.

I have a array in a array. the first one is the "category"  and in the category there are arrays wich have data.

Now i want to show all the category names with al the items that are in it, using smarty. My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [catAddons] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [name] => this is a addon group name
                    [group_categoryid] => 295
                    [group_description] => 
                    [group_optiontype] => single
                    [group_sort] => 0
                    [addons] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [addon_id] => 47
                                    [addon_group_id] => 25
                                    [addon_name] => bla
                                    [addon_priceoption] => paid
                                    [addon_purchaseprice] => 1.00
                                    [addon_price] => 2.00
                                    [addon_sort] => 0
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [addon_id] => 48
                                    [addon_group_id] => 25
                                    [addon_name] => nbalba
                                    [addon_priceoption] => free
                                    [addon_purchaseprice] => 0.00
                                    [addon_price] => 0.00
                                    [addon_sort] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

and im doing this:

```
{foreach from=$catAddons.0 key=k item=i}
    {$k} : {$i}
        {if $k eq 'addons'}
      {foreach from=$i.addons item=v}
          {$v}
      {/foreach}
        {/if}
{/foreach}
```

the first $ & $i is showing the data of the "category" group so this works. but now i want to loop the contents of [addons] but the second loop shows nothing. And when i remove the if statement it shows `Warning: Illegal string offset 'addons' in...`
 how can i do this ?

//EDIT UPDATED LOOP

```
{foreach from=$catAddons key=k item=i} <!-- ?? loop -->
    {$k} : {$i}
    {foreach from=$i key=k item=i} <!-- Group loop -->
    {$k} {$i}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

this one shows the data of all groups.. but then addons shows like this Addons : Array ... but i dont know how to loop this in the loop

Comment: Are you using smarty 2.x or 3.x? The 3.x syntax is much easier...

Comment: 2.6.3... i can not upgrade it not my website

Comment: ok just found out it is not working at all... the category name that it shows, is the actual [0] from the array so it does not loop also

Comment: What are you trying to print out?

Comment: a title -> addon_group_name and under the title there will be options the addons... and a group can have mutltiple options... and there are multiple groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through associative arrays in Smarty, use the following syntax:

```
{foreach from=$assoc_arr key=k item=i}
    {$k} : {$i}
{/foreach}
```

To loop through numerically-indexed (non-associative) arrays, use the following:

```
{foreach from=$num_arr item=i}
    {$i}
{/foreach}
```

So if you have a mix of numerical and associative arrays, you will have to dive down into them accordingly:

```
{foreach from=$catAddons item=x}                 <!-- numerically-indexed array -->
    {foreach from=$x key=k item=i}               <!-- associative array -->
        <p>key: {$k} => item: {$i}</p>
        {if $k eq 'addons'}                      <!-- access a nested array -->
            {foreach from=$i item=ix}            <!-- numerically-indexed array -->
                {foreach from=$ix key=k2 item=v} <!-- associative array -->
                    <p>k2: {$k2} => value: {$v}</p>
                {/foreach}
            {/foreach}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: I end up doing some weird section in a foreach construction... but it works.. thanks!